# OAuth flow for mobile application to communicate with Rest API secured by OAuth

Tags: rest, oauth

I've faced an interesting issue IMHO with OAuth and mobile application. I've found few similar questions on SO already, but have not found any relevant answer I'm afraid.

The application consist of the following:

- Rest API secured by OAuth
- Android mobile application (aka trusted client / official app) that consumes the API.

There are three ways for user to create an account:

- email / password combination
- Google account
- Facebook account

There are two main problems /I suppose both are connected with each other/:

1. What OAuth grant type should be used?
2. How to deal with 3rd party user registration?

**About issue #1**
I was thinking about using the **Resource Owner Password** grant /although I've found a bit different opinions about using it in native applications/ or the **Client Credentials** grant type. While dealing with Resource Owner Password grant type I can see an issue with the accounts created via Facebook or Google as they have no password.

**About issue #2**
Which party should be responsible for handling Facebook/Google registration? Backend or the mobile application? As in the current scenario there's no website, I presume the mobile app should be the responsible party.

Second problem regarding the external accounts: how do deal with them regarding the API secured by OAuth?

I appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you roll your own users, centralising the functionality of authorizing with third parties is a good idea. Your backend code should be able to finalize authorization with Facebook and Google. Regardless of where the authorization was initiated from.

Example.

1. User opens the app ExampleApp for the first time, sees the "sign up/log in with google" button and clicks it.
2. The app initiates the oauth-flow and designates a redirect_uri (i.e a callback) that resides in your own authorization layer, e.g https://exampleapp.com/google-auth-callback.
3. Then your server can exchange the authorization code for an access token -> fetch user identity from google and create a new user
4. Now the app needs the credentials to exampleapp.com/api, so the server generates an access token and returns that to the app via an app callback. i.e exampleapp. Basically the server can do a `302 Permanent Redirect` to a custom URL-schema such as `ExampleApp://?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN&expires_in=TIMESTAMP`
5. Now the app can communicate with your backend, and refresh tokens etc.

Note: I am assuming Oauth2 for your service provider, but roughly the same process could be used for Oauth1.